# Entity Framework. Ошибка повторной записи в бд при связи один ко многим

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

**Используется:** Entity Framework (Code First), SQLite.

Есть модели Topic и User. Пользователь может создавать много топиков.

```
public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}
```

Создаю объект топика, в нем объект пользователя, пишу в бд, все ок:

```
using (AppDbContext context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var user1 = new User
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Jon"
    };

    var topic1 = new Topic
    {
        Id = 1,
        Title = "First",
        User = user1
    };

    context.Topics.AddOrUpdate(topic1);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

### Проблема

Если добавить новый топик, но с тем же пользователем, возникнет исключение:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> ---
>
> constraint failed UNIQUE constraint failed: Users.Id

Т.е. повторно пытается вставить существующего пользователя, насколько я понял.
Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь не вставлялся повторно `Add`, а обновлялся `AddOrUpdate`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод AddOrUpdate используется только [при миграциях](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/), в других случаях лучше не использовать его.

Решить проблему можно с помощью метода [Attach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) и тогда при вызове SaveChanges не будет попытки сохранить юзера, поскольку подтянется контекст для объекта и EF будет знать о том, что он существует в бд и не претерпел изменений.

```
var entry = context.Entry(user1);
entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged
```

---

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    var user1 = new User
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Jon"
    };

    var topic1 = new Topic
    {
        Id = 2,
        Title = "First",
        User = user1
    };

    context.Users.Attach(user1);

    context.Topics.Add(topic1);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Или же можно указать UserId, без Attach. Результат тот же.

```
var topic1 = new Topic
{
    Id = 3,
    Title = "First",
    UserId = 1
};
```

Comment: Почитал про `AddOrUpdate`. Понял, что его не стоит использовать, т.к. при обновлении записей, если какие-то поля не переданы, то они автоматически будут устанавливаться в `null`. Скажите, пожалуйста, это основная причина? Может что-то упустил?

Comment: @Skrim Да, так. Еще метод находится в    System.Data.Entity.Migrations, что намекает :)